# Sculpting not working on both sides?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, mirror, sculpt

Hello so I have been having trouble with this issue I will give an example of my issue

[image]

It doesn't sculpt on the other side I need some help it is probably simple, but I can't figure it out on my own. I don't know whether to sculpt all the right sides first or is there another way.
Thank you.

Comment: There isn't enough information. Did you try applying transforms? (Object mode > object selected > Ctrl+A > Rotation and Scale, then sculpting). Do you use symmetry in sculpting and it's not working as expected?

Comment: make sure that the origin is at the center of your character, in Edit mode select all and in the header menu > Mesh > Symmetrize and choose the right angle in the Operator box, then try again to sculpt?